# Unable to hide tool-bar grip

Tags: wpf, toolbar, grip

I am trying to create a ToolBar in my WPF application.
I don't want the strip (as shown in the bellow figure) to show up, I just want all the items to be placed in the general area.

I tried setting the ToolBar.OverflowMode to Never ut it doesn't help.

[image: l]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Toolbar's control template, there is nothing that can remove that grip. You can set `ToolBarTray.IsLocked="True"` but this will remove only drag handle from the left hand side. As for the grip you will have to edit default ToolBar template (you can find one in Expression Blend directory, e.g. `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Expression\Blend 3\SystemThemes\Wpf\`), and remove `OverflowGrid` from it...